# React admin real search bar?

Tags: react-admin

I would like to implement a real search bar for a list view in react admin.

By real search bar by I mean a search bar that looks inside a list for a record with a similar matching name.

EXAMPLE:

List:

- Record 1: Juan
- Record 2: Adri

Actual behavior

- Search for Adri and list only contains record 2
- Search for Ju and list does not contain any records

Desired behavior:

- Search for Ju and list contains record 1
- Search for Adri and list contains record 2

Any ideas?

Comment: "It’s your responsibility to implement the full-text filtering capabilities in your dataProvider, or in your API" https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#full-text-search

Answer (score 0):

This is a function of your API and/or backend, not of react-admin.

Whatever you put into the filter will be sent as a filter parameter as per your dataProvider, but your backend API has to be set up to do that kind of partial search.

MaxAlex's comment is correct; although that quote from react-admin is specifically related to a more global full-text search, the same thing applies here.